# How does contract know where the fund (or the amount of Ether) is by executing "suicide"?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, selfdestruct

It's said if we run:

```
suicide(address recipient);
```

At the end of the contract, the recipient will receive the amount of Ether owned by the contract.

**Question** 1: How does the contract (and this function) know where the amount of Ether is?

**Question** 2: In the 1st example [here](https://www.ethereum.org/dao#add-a-complex-proposal-own-another-token), they have no "suicide", then how the funding is released to the recipient (or beneficiary)?

---

"payable" enables a function (and contract) to receive Ether, and it can keep track of the amount it receive  by using an array, e.g.

```
mapping (address => uint) balances;
```

**Question** 3: How does the contract claim the money it receives?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1)** The contract simply has the ether... For example:

Try `this.balance`

I'm unfamiliar with the exact assembly generated, but I would assume it does the following:

1) `recipient.send(this.balance)`

2) send kill opcode

It might be that it is a form of "delete"
Just like delete xyz[1234] recovers some gas

**Q2)** Unless a function that sends `beneficiary.send(this.balance)` funds could essentially be locked inside a contract, there is no "magic" going on, you can write terrible contracts if you want :)

**Q3)** As a contract receives funds via a payable function, it just has them, it doesn't need to claim it, unless it's dealing with receiving an ERC-20 token, but that's a whole different chapter

Comment: 1) There's a dedicated opcode `SELFDESTRUCT` that does everything.